# DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist - Chrome using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Kindly help me solve this issue. I have been facing it since last month. I dont know how to solve it anymore. I have tried adding this code but it still doesn't work. This occurred after I update the chrome browser.

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path\chromedriver.exe");`
`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();`
`options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model`
`options.addArguments("--headless"); //`
`options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems`

This is the original code. I'm new to selenium java so please help. :)

```
public class BrowserHelper {

public WebDriver driver;
private static final String CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe";

public List<WebDriver> driversList = new LinkedList<WebDriver>();

/**
 * 
 * @param logger
 * @param browserName
 * @param userEID
 * @return
 */
public WebDriver startBrowser(ExtentTest logger,String browserName, String userEID)
{
               try
               {
                             if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
                             {          
                                 
               System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "apache")    ;   
               WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
               HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
               chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
               ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
               options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            
          
               DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
               cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
               cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
               cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true); 
               driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
             
                       
               driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
               driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Chrome driver version: 109.0.5414.74
Chrome browser version: 109.0.5414.120

I've tried some of the codes from other forums but still not working.
This is the error in console:                                                                                                                                               `Starting ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{`[`#1172`](https://support.github.com/ticket/1172)`}) on port 42569`
`Only local connections are allowed.`
`Please see` [`https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations`](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations) `for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.`
`ChromeDriver was started successfully.`
`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`
`Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'`
`System info: host: 'CIOS-9302MSK-LX', ip: '192.168.1.229', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_361'`
`Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver`
`remote stacktrace: Backtrace:`
`(No symbol) [0x00406643]`
`(No symbol) [0x0039BE21]`
`(No symbol) [0x0029DA9D]`
`(No symbol) [0x002C1D8E]`
`(No symbol) [0x002BD3F0]`
`(No symbol) [0x002BA899]`
`(No symbol) [0x002F6917]`
`(No symbol) [0x002F655C]`
`(No symbol) [0x002EFB76]`
`(No symbol) [0x002C49C1]`
`(No symbol) [0x002C5E5D]`
`GetHandleVerifier [0x0067A142+2497106]`
`GetHandleVerifier [0x006A85D3+2686691]`
`GetHandleVerifier [0x006ABB9C+2700460]`
`GetHandleVerifier [0x004B3B10+635936]`
`(No symbol) [0x003A4A1F]`
`(No symbol) [0x003AA418]`
`(No symbol) [0x003AA505]`
`(No symbol) [0x003B508B]`
`BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76FA6BD9+25]`
`RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x776F8FD2+1218]`
`RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x776F8F9D+1165]`